# The interior of $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and as a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the usual topology and let $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ have the subspace topology, what is the interior of $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? What about the interior as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$? The answer gives $\varnothing$ and $(0,1)\times\{0\}$ respectively but I don't understand why.

The way I see it, $[0,1]\times \{0\}=\{(x,0): x\in [0,1]\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, then the interior is empty, since this set does not have any open subsets in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The way you see it is good, what is bothering you?

Comment: For the second case, you must give the subspace topology to $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ in which case it is "the same" as $\mathbb{R}$.  So the interior of $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ is the same as the interior of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: ok, so just use homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$?

Comment: @JimmyR Yes. Also I made that comment an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second case, you must give the subspace topology to $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ in which case it is "the same" as $\mathbb{R}$.  So the interior of $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ is "the same" as the interior of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$.